# ActionBar doesn´t change to Holo or Dark

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

Im trying to customize my ActionBar, I´m following this tutorial by Android Developers --> [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), but it doesn´t channge, I specified the theme in the Android Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" and, in my styles.xml:
```

And also I changed my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</style>
```

Also, I have the last version of the library:

[image]

And it is referenced in my App Grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cheescake.juno"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                                      

    `proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
 }
```

I followed all the steps and I dont know why my ActionBar is in theme light yet. Maybe can be a stupid error and I didn´t understand something, but I have 2 days with this problem =(

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

And in Manifest file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 1):

After specifying the colour of your theme e.g:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
.... 
</style>`

Add the following line to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
....
```